# Access a struct-field if the struct is part of a list

Tags: list, struct, field, racket

So I'm new to Racket and I'm trying to write a function that adds elements to a priority-queue. Therefore I need to access a struct-field of a struct that is the head of a list (in this case the list is called lst).

```
(define-struct abc (element p))

(define (function lst e)  
  (cond  
    [(and (abc? e) (> (**first lst-p**) e-p)) (...
```

`e` has to be of the type `abc` so that I can compare the field `p`. I know that I can access `p` of `e` by writing `e-p`, but I don't have any idea how to access `p` of the first element in the list (the list only contains types of the struct `abc`).

I hope somebody might be able to help. Thanks!

Comment: Please use meaningful variable name

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I can access p of e by writing e-p

When you define a struct, Racket defines auxiliary functions like `abc-p`, so it is not sufficient to just write `e-p` (it is unbound in that context); you have to apply `abc-p` it to the object from which you want to get the value:

```
(abc-p (abc 10 20))
=> 20
```

> I don't have any idea how to access p of the first element in the list

You need to read [Racket Reference: 4.9 Pairs and Lists](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html), lists are defines in Racket as chains of cons-cells: a cell has two slots, named `car` and `cdr` for historical reasons, where the `car` is used to store values, and the `cdr` points to another cons-cell, or the empty list `'()`.

To access the first element of a list named `lst`, you would write `(car lst)`. Note that if it is an error to call it on an empty list in Racket (more generally in Scheme), so you first need to check if the list is empty with `null?`.